# AngularJS : $httpBackend mock only some requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-mock

I use ngMock module to mock a several requests like so:

```
 $httpBackend.whenGET("/accounts").respond([obj]);
```

However, it seems that loading the module expects you to mock ALL requests.
So if I do any other request other than those I mocked, I get "Unexpected request" error.

How can I configure it so that it ONLY intercepts requests that I mock explicitly, and passes everything else through?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex and the passThrough() function built into $httpBackend.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend){
    $httpBackend.whenGET("/accounts").respond([obj]);
    //Pass everything else through
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\w+.*/).passThrough();
}));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore it still throws errors for some routes like /tapi/mds/info. Is there a better way?

Comment: Fundamentally this is a regex, so as a result you can probably just go with (/.*/).passThrough(), which is way more open ended but will let everything else through.

Comment: whats the point of that? does the order matter if I register new ones after that call?

Comment: nope, it does not just tested.... so this doesnt really answer the question then. I want to passthrough everything except what I explicity register.